# How to re-map array column values in select in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to re-map integer values from a Postgres array column in the select? This is what I have:

```
select unnest(tag_ids) from mention m where id = 288201;
 unnest  
---------
 -143503
 -143564
  125192
  143604
  137694

tag_ids is integer[] column
```

I would like to translate those numbers. Functions like `abs(unnest(..))` work but found I cannot use a CASE statement. Tx.

Comment: Translate to what?

Comment: Just different numbers 125192 -> 1234 etc.

Comment: The please explain the logic base on which the value 125192 is converted to 1234

Comment: There are a bunch of these remappings with no underlying logic or relationship between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do anything non-trivial with the elements from an array after unnesting, use the set-returning function like table:

```
select u.tag_id
from mention m   
  cross join unnest(m.tag_ids) as u(tag_id)
where m.id = 288201;
```

Now, `u.tag_id` is an integer column that you can use like any other column, e.g. in a CASE *expression*.